# Samsung Battery Life Extender - limit battery charging to 80% under Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, samsung

Some of you may have used Easy Settings app that's provided by Samsung for Windows OS. Similar Samsung's tool for Linux OS distributions isn't available.
I missed Battery Life Extender function the most: I don't want my battery to be unnecessarily fully charged when I don't often use laptop while on battery for long periods of time.

**How does one activate / deactivate Battery Life Extender under Ubuntu OS?**

[image: samsung battery life extender]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was tested and validated to work on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 - 14.04 x64 and Linux Mint 16 x64 - 17.3 x64 and Samsung NP300E5Z laptop.
Essentially, we need to change content of `/sys/devices/platform/samsung/battery_life_extender` file to 1 or 0.

**To turn on Battery Life Extender (run command from bash console):**

`sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/samsung/battery_life_extender <<<1`

**To turn off Battery Life Extender (run command from bash console):**

`sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/samsung/battery_life_extender <<<0`

*You may also use text editor, I used Sublime Text once.
There also seem to exist one or more aliases of above mentioned file, one being:* `/sys/bus/platform/devices/samsung/battery_life_extender`

Comment: I tested and validated it because I used this workaround for straight 2 years.
"This answer seems very much a copy / paste from somewhere" - I'll try to accept this as a complement to my writing style.

Comment: It is just that first line, yes take it as a compliment, it was the professional way it is written, that made me think it was a copy/paste :) +1